# MSSQL trigger: fill in rest of table based

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like this:

| Date | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 = Col1*Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 03-03-2021 | 100 | 2 | 200 |
| 03-03-2020 | 200 | 1 | 200 |
| 04-20-2029 | NULL | NULL | NULL |

I want to create 2 triggers that do the following:

1. After u user inputs a new row, if col1 and col2 are null, search another table for the values of col1 and col2. If col1 is null, only search for col2. If col2 is null, only search for col1.
2. Upon update of col1, col2, recalculate col3.

Am having trouble getting started on this. Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: You start with `CREATE TRIGGER`.

Comment: _Upon update of col1, col2, recalculate col3_ no - create a computed column, avoiding the extra work of recalculating whenever the value of a dependent column is changed.